# sIFR in Javascript news rotator?

Tags: sifr

I'm using sIFR on a website that is database driven and it works great. However, I have a news rotator on the home page and sIFR won't replace the text on the tile below the rotating image, so I have to create images for this each time.

Example of the site is http://www.aucklandcityfc.com. Put home.asp on the end of the URL to see what it looks like trying to run sIFR by default.

What I'd like to be able to do is use sIFR to replace that text as well, and then other people can add stories through the CMS.

Alternatively, if there's a better rotator (or possibly a Flash application) that anyone knows of, please let me know.

Thanks,
Adam

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the new text and then replace the element again; or use the `replaceText` API method to change the text inside an existing sIFR Flash movie.

Comment: Thanks Mark - sorry to sound like a bit of a noob, but what is the code I should use to replace the element again? It creates a loop within Javascript which just spits out <h1>#HEADLINE#</h1> - do I need to put some Javascript in front of each of those?

Thanks again

Comment: There's not enough context for me to be able to answer.